# Which GameObject should I put the animator on?

Tags: unity, animation, gameobject

I have a GameObject.  One of its children is an empty GameObject, whose children are the body parts which need to be animated.

```
Character (root)
--->Body
--->--->Body Parts
```

Should I put the animator on the root GameObject ("Character")?  Or on the empty child ("Body")?  Does it matter? What benefits would one way offer over the other?  Or is there another approach I should be taking?

This is for 2D sprites/animations.  I am trying to figure this out before making all of the animations to avoid redoing them.

Comment: Why you have an empty child called body? Just for the sake of organisation?

Comment: @dh yes. also figured if i ever want to rotate/translate/resize the entire body without affecting animation of individual body parts, thatd be a good place to do it consistently

Comment: Well, not giving a really detailed answer, but overall you would probably want the AnimatorController in the Character object. If, let's say, later you want to animate a familiar, or companion, or a mount, that shouldn't be tied to the body, then it would be ready to just improve the animation to change not only the Body and it's children, but the other GameObjects as well. But it's just thinking of later improvement of the game, other than that I can't think of what difference you would have in the actual situation choosing the root of the body object.